# D3 Collapsible child nodes going around root node in circles

Tags: css, d3.js, css-transitions, css-transforms

how can i space the Collapsible tree nodes in circles going around the root node?Example of picture below.second image what i currently have now.
i know it has something to do with the X and Y position in this method.But i just can't figure out how.
original code i got it from [Original code here](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd)

```
function update(source) {

    // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
    var treeData = treemap(root);

    // Compute the new tree layout.
    var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
        links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);
    debugger
    // Normalize for fixed-depth.

    nodes.forEach(function (d) {
        //i know i have to do something here
        d.y = d.depth * 180;

    });

// Transition to the proper position for the node
//then it will update the transform and translate
enter code here
    nodeUpdate.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
        });
```

[image: What i want to do]

[image]

Comment: reason for down voting?so that i can improve on the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

solved.this is my outcome.
instead of using translate for my rotating.i use rotate class with transform.
[image]